# When was cannabis legalized in the Netherlands?

Tags: law, drugs

In which date was cannabis legalized in the Netherlands? I mean the introduction of coffee shops

Comment: I googled for it but I was not able to find anything

Comment: Was it ever even *illegal* there?

Comment: Not sure at all!

Comment: I do know that it is generally argued among legalization proponents here in the USA that that only reason it was ever banned here was because it was viewed as something "Mexicans" did (iow: just a matter of racisim). They wouldn't have that issue in the Netherlands, I'm guessing.

Comment: The main reason because it was banned was the pressure of oil companies. Indeed hemp is a valid alternative to petroleum for many applications, so oil companies started a media-fight against marijuana, in order to make the production of hemp much harder

Comment: Most 'recreational' drugs were only banned in the moral outrage era of prohibition. In WWI heroin and cocaine could be bought freely in London

Comment: @T.E.D. Oh don't worry, Europe has it's share of racism. It might not be against "the mexicans", but it can be another group.

Answer (score 10):

Contrary to popular myth, cannabis is *not* legal in the Netherlands. But the current *de facto* liberal policy dates to 1976.

> In 1976 the Netherlands adopted a **formal written policy of non-enforcement** for violations involving possession or sale of up to 30 grams of cannabis. [<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.rand.org/pubs/working_papers/WR768.html) *(emphasis mine)*

That study I cited is worth perusing if you're interested in the subject.